# JComboBox mistake with repaint() method

Tags: java, jcombobox

I am new to Java and I'm creating a clock with time zone.
I have a little problem with `JComboBox`'s `repaint` method.
If I put `repaint()` in my code I can't see the `JComboBox` in the Applet window, and if I remove `repaint()` then it is visible. As you know it is very necessary to put repaint() in your code.

What am I doing wrong?

`
package apps;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Alarm2 extends JFrame implements  ItemListener,Runnable{

```
private Graphics dbg;

private Image dbImage;

JComboBox c=new JComboBox();

Thread t;

int h,m,s;

boolean alarm=false;

String time="";



TextField tf=new TextField("SEX:",10);

Alarm2(){





  setTitle("BALVEER");

  setSize(250,250);

  setResizable(false);

  setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  c.addItem("MALE");

  c.addItem("FEMALE");

  setBackground(Color.GREEN);


  c.addItemListener(this);

  add(c);

  add(tf);

  setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,10,195));

  setVisible(true);


}
```

public void aisha(){

```
t=new Thread(this);

t.start();



}
```

public void run(){

```
   try{

       while(true){

       Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

        h=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

        m=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


        s=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        t.sleep(1000);

        time=" "+h+" : "+m+" : "+s;

               repaint();



       }



   }

   catch(Exception e){



   }
```

}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){

```
  tf.setText("SEX: "+e.getItem());

}



public void paint(Graphics g){

dbImage =createImage(getWidth(),getHeight()); 


dbg=dbImage.getGraphics();

draw(dbg);

g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0,this);

}

public void draw(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.red);

    g.drawString("TIME:"+time, 50, 100);



}

public static void main(String[] args) {

      Alarm2 java=new Alarm2();

      java.aisha();

}
```

}`

Comment: Never call `repaint` from `paint` or `paintComponent`.  It creates an infinite loop, since `repaint` will cause `paint` to be called again.  That said, your statement is incorrect:  You don't need to call `repaint` unless the parameters for your custom drawing have changed.

Comment: Hey guy,...may be you are right, but repaint() wasn't problem just before the JComboBox!!! and here you are ....i just edit this program now check it again!!!there is actually JcomboBox creating problem!!Here Jcombo box and "TIME"  is not visible at one time....Best on your concept solve this problem,....thanks in advance